# Can we use some other type of time picker?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I want this type of time picker in my app but the default one in my device is

[image: Which I don't want]

But I want This

[image: Which I want]

I got some source code but not filling my need

```
case REQUEST_TIMEI1:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT ,mTimeSetListener1, hour, minute, true);
```

Comment: Check this libraries: https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker or https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker or https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: Why not? Make a custom View. Or pick some ready made library on Android Arsenal.

Comment: I kinda like the radial picker better... It's more clock-like

Comment: I wasn't able to understand that cause I am a bit silly...not exactly...I am just 13 years old. github goes from above my head

Comment: Ehh... What? what is the problem with your age? Just learn how to be implemented github libraries in Android Studio and fun!

Comment: Blah.... I hate Github, pls don't tell authorities about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply put these lines in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
}
```

and follow this link [here.](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) Still you face any problem feel free to ask

**Update**

You can also use this

```
compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
```

follow this [link](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers) for further instruction

Some more to follow. It might be helpful for others

[1. Sublime Picked](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker)

[2. Material date Range picker](https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker)

[3. Silk Cal](https://github.com/NLMartian/SilkCal)

[4. Calendar List view](https://github.com/traex/CalendarListview)

[5. Android-Week-View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

[6. Android-MonthCalendarWidget](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-MonthCalendarWidget)